# Rails : Send email via Gmail in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, gmail, host

I want to send email via my gmail account in PRODUCTION. It works great in local host.

In my environment.rb I have :

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address             => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :port                => 587,
 :domain              => "myhost.com",
 :authentication      => "plain",
 :user_name           => "name@myhost.com",
 :password            => "mypassword",
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
```

}

And in my production.rb file :

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'gmail.com' }
```

But it doesn't work and I have that error :

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
```

Any ideas ? My app is deployed on Heroku.
For the `host` what do I have to put ?

Thanks !

Comment: If you have an answer to this, I really would like to know.

Answer (score 2):

Host should be `www.yourapp.com`. My settings for gmail on Heroku look like this, and they work:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'www.myapp.com' }
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "gmail.com",
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name => "user@myapp.com",
    :password => "mypassword"
}
```